# Как организовать connect by в mysql

Tags: mysql

Итак имеем:

```
 Server version: 5.1.40-community
```

Как мне сделать `connect by start with prior` и т.д.

Табличка тегов и подтегов, у подтегов свои подтеги в неизвесное количество уровней.

```
id;tag_id;name
пишу
select id from tag start with tag_id=0 connect by tag_id prior id
```

Вылетает ошибка, говоря о неправильности синтаксиса. Понимая, что connect by может и не быть в мускуле, как мне использовать альтернативу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению в MySQL нет штатной возможности выбирать иерархические структуры.

Как варианты альтернативы:

- Писать хранимую процедуру, которая рекурсивно прочитает все дерево попутно заполняя результатами выборки временную таблицу. Вызывать ее, и дальше читать обычным SELECT-ом.
- Проиндексировать дерево алгоритмом Nested Sets. Он даст возможность делать выборки без ограничения по вложенности.

**UPD:**

По поводу первого варианта.

```
# Таблица где хранится все дерево
CREATE TABLE table_tree(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_parent INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY id_parent (id_parent)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

# Буферная таблица для выборки дерева
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_tree_nodes (
    id INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = HEAP
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

# Процедура которая эту таблицу заполнит потомками от (in_id INT)
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS gen_tree_nodes;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE gen_tree_nodes(IN in_id INT)
  SQL SECURITY INVOKER
  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE _eof   TINYINT(1)   DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _id    INT(11)      DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE _title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE cur_children CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT id, title FROM table_tree WHERE id_parent = in_id;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
    SET _eof = 1;

    OPEN cur_children;
    FETCH cur_children INTO _id, _title;
    WHILE !_eof DO
        INSERT INTO tmp_tree_nodes VALUE (_id, _title);
        CALL gen_tree_nodes(_id); # рекурсиный вызов
        FETCH cur_children INTO _id, _title;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur_children;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Выборку делаем так.

```
# Предварительная очистка буферной таблицы
DELETE FROM tmp_tree_nodes;
# Системная установка допустимой глубины рекурсии
SET SESSION max_sp_recursion_depth = 100;
# Загрузка в буфер всех потомков для определенного узла
CALL gen_tree_nodes(1);
# Выборка из буфера
SELECT * FROM tmp_tree_nodes;
```

Довольно громоздко, но работает. Сразу оговорюсь: это наброски "на коленке", в своих разработках я этот метод не использую, и поэтому могу не знать возможных подводных камней.

Для большинства своих проектов я все же выбрал 2-й вариант. Один раз написал алгоритмы вставки, перемещения, удаления узлов, и имею полноценное легко-управляемое дерево.

**UPD2:**

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mysql/63883/) человек расписал вариант управления деревом Nested Sets на уровне триггеров. Костыль, конечно. Имхо, более верный метод управлять деревом не триггерами, а принудительным вызовом соответствующих функций. Это даст гибкость и избавит от постоянного передергивания триггера при правке данных не связанных с структурой дерева. Но это хороший вариант прозрачного управления деревом на уровне связки родитель-потомок.

Comment: Пожалуйста, по подробнее про пункт 1 и 2!) Я такого ответа и ждал, процедуру сам не смог найти. Попробую поискать второй пункт, но хотелось бы пример.

Comment: Второй нашел, слишком сложно и придется перекроить метод заполнения данной структуры из админки.

Comment: @org, расписал примерную реализацию первого варианта

Comment: Получилось нагнуть под свои задачи, так что ответ тру!)

Comment: Есть только один нюанс! Данная схема не ложится в память, а ложится в таблицу. Возникают коллизии когда пользователи борются за одну и ту же таблицу, ну либо недостоверная выборка у некоторых. Решил это так: совместил первый и отчасти второй способ.

Comment: Что касается древовидных структур - SQL не может предоставить гибкости по определению =)